# AWS Cognito User Pool + Social providers for auth/log in

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

**Hi guys, I have a user auth/sign-in problem:**

- The project is in react-native
- Backend is on AWS, therefore we are using Cognito user pool + identity pools.
- Our app should authenticate users only via Google or Apple -> meaning no local/AWS username/password.
- After the authentication of the user, I want to get his/hers token ID in order to access our Gateway API secured with the authorizer expecting this id token.

What I have done:

1. Created and set up apple/google dev console and got google app id and apple team id, key & identifier.
2. Created Cognito user pool + identity pool and added id from step one

Now, I want to make it work on FE. I want to have custom buttons that have will have on press functions that invoke sign-in process. Also I would like to skip generated Cognito hosted UI for sign-in and go directly to the given provider (I think via `Auth.federatedSignIn({customProvider: "provider"}`). Can this be embedded in the app? Is somewhere on GIT an example? Can someone elaborate more on this, please? I kidn of need OAuth flow with AWS functionality minus AWS generated UI...

I couldn't find an exact answer anywhere. If there will be any unclear parts, I will elaborate more. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When navigating to the authorization endpoint you can pass an additional parameter in the query string `identity_provider` as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html#get-authorize-request-parameters).

This instantly redirects the user to the IDPs sign-in and consent page without showing the hosted UI.

Comment: Thank you, but somehow I tried this and it did not work for me. Fortunately, I have found another way...

Comment: Also, I have a question for you. I want to authenticate users via Apple SignIn (SignInWithApple). I can do that but I want his/hers email and that does not work. I can either force user pool scope to have email mandatory and then authentication doesn't work or scope as none and would not get the email (from JWT). Google works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to bypass the hosted and generated Cognito UI. Just inspect the element (login button) and copy the link. Works like a charm!